# TRANWRD doesn't replace properly

Tags: string, sas

I was trying to progressively remove each /* */ comment pair on the same line by using the tranwrd function. However, the replacement doesn't happen for some reason.

Here's the code:

```
data _null_;
 str="/* Comment 1 */ /* Comment 2 */ /* Comment 3 */ /* Comment 4 */";
 do while(1);
    startc=find(str,"/*");
    endc=find(str,"*/");
    put startc endc;
    if startc = 0 then leave;
    else do;
      temp=substr(str,startc,endc-startc+2);
      put "temp: " temp;
      str=tranwrd(str,temp,"");
      put "str: " str;
    end;
end; 
run;
```

The code goes into infinite loop because although temp gets the value of "/* Comment 1 */", TRANWRD is unable to make a replacement for some reason.

Comment: If you're doing the above in a real world example, I highly recommend using (and learning if needed) regular expressions (PRXMATCH etc.).  Code parsing (such as quote or parentheses matching) is very complex and is much easier with regular expressions, when you have the possibility of nesting, which isn't really possible with `/* */` but does exist in other aspects of code parsing, and even this example is shorter done in regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Joe!
I'm new to SAS, so I haven't messed around with regexes yet. I'll be sure to give them a go, though.

Comment: I also reverted the title; the issue isn't related to a particular version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to TRIM the argument for finding (`temp`).  Otherwise it has extraneous spaces on the end.  Remember, string variables in SAS always have their full length - so if it is a 200 long string with `"ABCDE"` in it, it really is `"ABCDE                     "` (up to 200).

```
data _null_;
 str="/* Comment 1 */ /* Comment 2 */ /* Comment 3 */ /* Comment 4 */";
 do while(1);
    startc=find(str,"/*");
    endc=find(str,"*/");
    put startc endc;
    if startc = 0 then leave;
    else do;
      temp=substr(str,startc,endc-startc+2);
      put "temp: |" temp "|";
      str=tranwrd(str,trim(temp),"");
      put "str: " str;
    end;
end; 
run;
```

See the | | around temp; it has at least one extra space around it.  Your example was fortuitous in that you incorrectly added 2 to the length (should add one); since all of your `temp` arguments are identical in length this wouldn't have come up if you had added 1, but in a real world example this is presumably not the case.

Further, if you want it replaced with nothing, as opposed to a single space, you need to use `TRANSTRN` and `TRIMN` (which I think are 9.2+).  The above code really replaces it with a single space.  SAS does not have a concept of `""`, character null/missing is always `" "`.  `TRIMN` and `TRANSTRN` allow you to make this replacement as a sort of workaround.